# How to obtain the optical constants (dielectric function or complex conductivity) of a material from its band structure?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, conductors, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators

I know that the complex conductivity ($\sigma = \sigma_1+i\sigma_2$) is related to the dielectric function ($\epsilon = \epsilon_1+i\epsilon_2$) by:
$$ \epsilon_1 = 1 - \frac{4\pi\sigma_2}{\omega} \\\epsilon_2 = \frac{4\pi\sigma_1}{\omega} $$
and I also know that, for semiconductors, the following relation exists:
$$\sigma=\sigma_0e^{-\frac{E_{gap}}{2k_BT}}$$ where $E_{gap}$ is the band gap.
My question is, can either of these quantities be obtained from the band structure of other types of materials, like superconductors/insulators/insulators? What other information might be required to do so?